# How to Add XML to XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML file `original.xml` content:

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
    
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>89</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>a5b20593-3a25-4501-bc5a-04eb87069c46</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2022-04-19</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>11:57:00</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0111010">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:Note>مبيعات الجوال</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
    <cac:ContractDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    </cac:ContractDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>1</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>

</Invoice>
```

and want to add this XML file content `content1.xml` under `Invoice`:

```
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>

        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
```

And this file content `content2.xml` under `</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>`:

```
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">ARnYp9mE2YHYsdi5INin2YTYsdim2YrYs9mKAg8zMDA0NDczMjgxMDAwMzMDFDIwMjItMDQtMTlUMTE6NTc6MDBaBAYxNTMuNzAFBTIzLjcwBixoMmpNWHFnd05TeEdCY0JCeWJkcUQwb3k1MFNoNlRPQzFoRnZ6L2hONldZPQdYMFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEYYMMoOaFYAhMO/steotfZyavr6p11SSlwsK9azmsLY7b1b+FLhqMArhB2dqHKboxqKNfvkKDePhpqjui5hcn0QghANswMm535QvQd/8xuP6t5MyLO1BSrjVQbMB3+E/8DGdECSB2ABXdBDP9qEvus/nj7v63yoBwq+dT6gSBflIyAbKlDg==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
     </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
      </cac:Signature>
```

the file will be :

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
       <ext:UBLExtension>
       </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>89</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>a5b20593-3a25-4501-bc5a-04eb87069c46</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2022-04-19</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>11:57:00</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0111010">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:Note>مبيعات الجوال</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
    <cac:ContractDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    </cac:ContractDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>1</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>QR</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">ARnYp9mE2YHYsdi5INin2YTYsdim2YrYs9mKAg8zMDA0NDczMjgxMDAwMzMDFDIwMjItMDQtMTlUMTE6NTc6MDBaBAYxNTMuNzAFBTIzLjcwBixoMmpNWHFnd05TeEdCY0JCeWJkcUQwb3k1MFNoNlRPQzFoRnZ6L2hONldZPQdYMFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEYYMMoOaFYAhMO/steotfZyavr6p11SSlwsK9azmsLY7b1b+FLhqMArhB2dqHKboxqKNfvkKDePhpqjui5hcn0QghANswMm535QvQd/8xuP6t5MyLO1BSrjVQbMB3+E/8DGdECSB2ABXdBDP9qEvus/nj7v63yoBwq+dT6gSBflIyAbKlDg==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
     </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <cac:Signature>
      <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
      </cac:Signature>
    <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
        <cac:Attachment>
            <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>

</Invoice>
```

How can I add them in that order?

Comment: What have you tried so far? PHP has several ways to manipulate XML data. I would personally try [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) first.

Comment: @rickdenhaan: I'd normally often also, but in this case DOMDocument looks much more straight forward, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72679346/367456).

Answer (score 1):

For the orignal document you first prepend the first XML fragment and then you append the second XML fragment. It is more or less literal to your question, only that (here with `DOMDocument`) you can only append/prepend `DOMNode`(s):

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

$import = new class extends DOMDocument {
    public function __invoke(string $path): DOMDocumentFragment|bool|null
    {
        return @($_ = $this->createDocumentFragment())
            ->appendXML(file_get_contents($path)) ? $_ : null;
    }
};

$import->load(__DIR__ . '/original.xml');
$import->documentElement->prepend($import(__DIR__ . '/content1.xml'));
$import->documentElement->append($import(__DIR__ . '/content2.xml'));
$import->save('php://output');

echo 'php version', PHP_VERSION, ' with ext-dom ', phpversion("dom"), ' and lib-xml ', LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION, "\n";
```

This example code outputs the XML result to standard output.

Error are suppressed (`@` error suppression operator) when loading the XML from `content{1,2}.xml` as it is with warnings, the result looks good in your case and you can make the errors available by removing the suppression.

PHP version 8.1.7 with ext-dom 20031129 and lib-xml 2.9.14.

Comment: Thanks for solution but the `content1.xml` added under `xml deceleration` and I want it under `<invoice>` and contet2.xml need it under `</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>`

Comment: @MohammadKhaled: Try prefixing append and prepend with `documentElement->`

Comment: could you explain it by example? :)

Comment: @MohammadKhaled: Please see the updated answer. It just was missing.

Comment: the `content1` is OK thanks but `content2.xml` can I specify it to be append under `<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:UUID>1</cbc:UUID>
    </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>` ?

Comment: @MohammadKhaled: Yes, just use the appropriate parent element, I leave this is an exercise to the reader.

Comment: can show it ? =D